# Convert nested dictionary to flat pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

How can I convert a nested dictionary into a flat pandas df? Something such as this:

```
my_dict = {'Level1': {'Level21': {'Level31': 'some_value_31'},
  'Level22': {'Level31': 'some_value_32'},
  'Level23': {'Level31: 'some_value_31', 'Level32': 'some_value41'},
  'Level24': {'Level31': 'some_value32', 'Level32': 'some_value42'}}}
```

To something like this:

```
Level1              Level31          Level32
Level21             Some_value31     NaN
Level22             Some_value32     NaN
Level23             Some_value31     Some_value41
Level24             Some_value32     Some_value42
```

I tried something like this:

```
df = pd.concat({k: pd.DataFrame(v).T for k, v in my_dict.items()})
```

But what happens is, Level1 actually moves down at the row level as opposed to becoming a column for level2 values:

```
                                Level31          Level32
Level1    Level21               Some_value31     NaN
          Level22               Some_value32     NaN
          Level23               Some_value31     Some_value41
          Level24               Some_value32     Some_value42
```

Is there some simple method to move this up, or pop this level1 value into the column for the level2 fields?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

```
df = pd.DataFrame(my_dict["Level1"]).T.reset_index().rename(columns = {"index":"Level1"})
```

Output -

|  | Level1 | Level31 | Level32 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | Level21 | some_value_31 | nan |
| 1 | Level22 | some_value_32 | nan |
| 2 | Level23 | some_value_31 | some_value41 |
| 3 | Level24 | some_value32 | some_value42 |

Comment: Thank you! How does this compare when there is another level within the dictionary? I.e. a 4th level in the example above? I'm trying to understand how the above works and how it would work if more levels were added to the dict

Comment: Then you'll probably have to create a recurring function for this.